# I want to be able to separately sort multiple sections of information, and be able to change the column they are sorted by

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my sheet I have four sections of rows and columns I want to keep separate from each other.
I would like to be able to sort the rows of each section by the value in the columns.
I would also like to be able to change which column the section is sorted by. Sometimes I want to sort by column A, sometimes by column B, and so on. Column A contains names, column B-F contains colours (i.e. green, red, white).
A Google Apps Script or a checkbox system might work, but I am far from adept at Google Sheets, so I have no idea where I would even begin with such a system.

[Link to a copy of the sheet (with names replaced by letters)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOmeirt5Wrm-djrbHZmJm48s7i9zL5oh4T4flNI6as0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Link to a minimal example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOmeirt5Wrm-djrbHZmJm48s7i9zL5oh4T4flNI6as0/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried using the filter setting under Data > Create New Filter, but this limits the filtering to one of four sections at a time.
I looked into the filter function, but it does not seem to be what I was looking for.
I looked into the sort function, but it seems you can not change the column it sorts by unless you change the function manually.

Comment: A `QUERY()` based formula referencing a cell where you decide which column you want to sort it by may help, but in order to make it easier for folks to understand your difficulty, you'd have to make available a practical example, with the data as it is and the expected output.

Comment: Try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces what you want to achieve that way the community can help you in a better way.

Comment: Perhaps [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOmeirt5Wrm-djrbHZmJm48s7i9zL5oh4T4flNI6as0/edit?usp=sharing) is better as an explanation?